# Power Bi Cant subtract percentage

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do I subtract percentages in Power BI? Cant get it to work.

```
Measure1 = 1
Measure2 = 0.9
Measure3 = [Measure1] - [Measure2]
```

This ofcourse works fine, but when I try to format my measures to show everything in percentages, I get the "Cannot convert value 100% of type Text to type Number"-Error when I try to visualize Measeure3 with the below code.

```
Measure1 = Format(1,"0.0%")
Measure2 = Format(0.9,"0.0%")
Measure3 = [Measure1] - [Measure2]
```

How do i calculate and visualize this easy formula when the figures are formated as percentages?

Comment: Why are you using the `FORMAT` function. Why not just define Measure1 as 1 and set its format as %?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your suggestion! That would work in this specific case, but lets say I want to use a `switch`-funktion that alter between measure3 and measure4 (where measure4 is just an integer). Then I want m3 to be shown as percentage and m4 to be shown as an integer. Dont I need to format my figures then?

Comment: Perhaps you should update your post with a more realistic example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need smth like that

```
VALUE(LEFT( [Measure1],LEN( [Measure1])-1)) - VALUE(LEFT( [Measure2],LEN( [Measure2])-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to do the formatting after subtraction operation: Like this:

```
Measure3 = FORMAT((1 - 0.9),"0.0%")
```

On a visual Card,

[image: Visual Formatting Section]

Note: Format() Function returns a text as a result, not a number.

```
TestIfText_Measure3 = ISTEXT('Measure Table'[Measure3])
```

[image: Test]

Comment: Thanks for clarification that "Format" returns text, did not know that. And that explains a bit of the problem!

Comment: Yes, You can easily check it by using ISTEXT(Your_Measure). I updated it on my visual card above. Check it.